# Build a dictionary from large lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists, `A_flat`, which contains 1,000,000 sentences, and `B_flat` which for each sentence contains a list of four labels. This is my code:

```
# Find indices of sentences with length <= max_length
short_sent_indices = [i for i, sent in enumerate(A_flat) if len(sent.split()) <= max_length]

# Build a dictionary mapping each label to the indices of sentences that have that label
label_to_indices = {label: [i for i in short_sent_indices if label in B_flat[i]] for label in set(label for i in short_sent_indices for label in B_flat[i] if label != 'None')}
label_sets = [{label for label in B_flat[i] if label != 'None'} for i in short_sent_indices]

# Find positive pairs using set intersection
positive_pairs = {(i, j) for i in range(len(short_sent_indices)) for j in range(i + 1, len(short_sent_indices)) if bool(label_sets[i] & label_sets[j])}
```

This code is very slow and only works for a small subset of `A_flat`. How can I enhance this code to make it work for 1 million sentences?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into difficulties? For instance, have you tried chunking your list and processing it in bits, or using a generator instead of a list comprehension? Have you done anything to determine where the computation starts to fail or is inefficient? (What is "slow" in this case?)

Comment: The slow part is # Build a dictionary mapping each label to the indices of sentences that have that label and finding the positive pairs.
 I can not do this in parts; I need to do it all at once

Comment: @Abrar the list comprehension there will be slow because you create the set of all possible labels, and iterate the whole of `short_sent_indices` once for every label. Instead, build up `label_by_indices` sentence by sentence, adding any new labels you find as keys.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: Actually, what is `label_to_indices` needed for? In this code it's created but never used.

Comment: I need it later for validation, but finding the positive pairs is even slower than the label_to_indices step.

Comment: @Abrar OK, so this should be a faster way to do it. `label_to_indices = {}; for i in short_sent_indices: for label in B_flat[i]: label_to_indices.setdefault(label, []).append(i)`

Comment: Then, you could try instead building `positive_pairs` from `label_to_indices`. Something like `positive_pairs=set(); for indices in label_to_indices.values(): positive_pairs.update(itertools.combinations(indices, 2))`